# Snake game ,how to move snake part according to its direction?

Tags: libgdx

I am making Snake game in Libgdx but I do not know how to move the Snake parts according to its head direction. Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

Only the head moves, the others move to its parent.

Imagine the snake's future position as the head, then each following part will move to its head.

In particular

Let A = array of parts where each part-1 is that part's "parent"
then you can move all parts except the "Actual head" to its "head".
At this point, the two leading heads have the same position.
Move the "actual head" to the "new head position"

I think this sounds about right.

Comment: A more efficient way to do the movement would be just taking the last part of the snake and positionate it to the new head-position.

Answer (score 0):

You will use a variable that holds the current movement direction and a list that has all the snake parts. 

At each movement phase you will compare the movement variable to the 4 possible states (LEFT, UP, RIGHT, BOTTOM) and increment / decrement the x / y of the first element in the list (Head). The rest of the parts take the position of the elements positioned in front of them in the list

```
for (int i=1 ; i< list.size() ; i++ )
list.get(i).setPosition( list.get(i-1).getX(), list.get(i-1).getY() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a arrayList in which you have to save x and y position of snakeHead's last x and y position. Use this arrayList to give x and Y position to rest of the bodypart.